# Laplace delta pressure

Tags: pressure

For an air bubble into the water the energy change due to the pressure forces on the system, changing infinitesimally the volume, is $\delta W=\Delta P dV$ where $\Delta P$ is $P_{in} - P_{out}$. Can you explain me why the work is not the classical $\delta W=-P dV$?

edit: Is it because the bubble is not isolated and so i should consider that the water energy changes by $-P_{out} \Delta V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work term $\Delta P\,dV$ refers to the increasing surface area (and consequent increasing surface energy) as the bubble expands.

The bubble's surface area and volume for radius $R$ are $A=4\pi R^2$ and $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$, respectively.

The infinitesimal work $w$ to increase surface area $A$ with surface energy $\gamma$ is $w=\gamma\,dA=\gamma(8\pi R)dR$.

The Laplace pressure difference $\Delta P$ can be [shown to equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation) $2\gamma/R$; thus, $w=\Delta P(4\pi R^2)dR=\Delta P\,dV$.